# MySQL: Storing item properties

Tags: mysql, optimization, storage

I need some advice on what would be the best way to store specific information on a `MySQL Database`.

I have an array of hundreds of items, each one with a specific property `color`. There is total of 9 colors available and each item may have any combination of those colors.

**Ex:**

```
Item1: "green,blue,orange"
Item2: "red,grey",
Item3: "green",
(...)
```

I'm wondering what would be the best way to store that for maximum performance and acessibility.
Should I just store the array of colors on a single cell and `explode()` it when necessary, or what would be a better approach to this ?

I want to do this the best way possible to avoid hassles later so I could use some opinions from rather more experienced people.

Many thanks!

Comment: `google://many to many`

Comment: PS: "for maximum performance and acessibility" --- forget these buzzwords. While you're a newbie your code will be terrible inefficient and insecure. And even when you will become an intermediate - it still will be the case, sometimes.